# What kernel modules would be responsible when using files in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scsi

When the fopen() function is invoked in C, it issues a system call to the kernel. I would like to know which kernel modules are responsible in processing the system call and returning the file descriptor to the calling program. Are these kernel modules also responsible in handling read() and write() operations ? If not, which modules are responsible.

I'm fiddling around with issuing SCSI commands and the information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> When the fopen() function is invoked in C, it issues a system call to the kernel.

Not exactly. `fopen(3)` is a *library* function that eventually calls `open(2)`, a system call.

> I would like to know which kernel modules are responsible in processing the system call and returning the file descriptor to the calling program.

None. In Linux, the system calls are all handled by the core kernel, not a module. See `fs/open.c`.

> Are these kernel modules also responsible in handling read() and write() operations ? If not, which modules are responsible.

Same deal. See `fs/read_write.c`.

At the point the kernel is given a path to open, it will first determine the mount point where the file you're requesting lives. A filesystem will be mounted at that mount point, and that filesystem is implemented is implemented in a module.

Filesystems work on top of block devices. And those block devices (e.g. SCSI, IDE) are also implemented in modules.

> I'm fiddling around with issuing SCSI commands and the information would be appreciated.

Have a look here:
http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg3_utils.html

Comment: Make sense that it would be part of the core kernel. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Daedalus modules will be involved during the processing of the open/read/write syscalls though.  The main entry point for the syscalls are in the core kernel, but different filesystem types are often implemented as modules, and obviously for a "normal" file access you'll need to access the filesystem at some point to handle these sytem calls.